# How to make image fit column in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image, css

If had :

```
<div class = "row">

    <div class = "column-md-6">
        <p>Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph
         Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph. 
         Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph. 
         Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph. 
         Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph. 
         </p>
    </div>

    <div class = "col-md-6">
         <img src = "#">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make that image the exact height and width of the paragraph to the left of it?

Comment: do you want that image should take whole area of ```col-md-6```

Comment: yes that is what I am looking for

Comment: How do you want the image displayed on devices with width below `991px`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, give a background image rather than giving the image inside a `img` tag

```
<div class = "col-md-6 my_img">
     <img src = "#">
</div>
```

and you css will be:

```
.my_img{
  height:300px; /* give your required height */
  background:url('your image url or location');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I tell the height of the paragraph next to it (where you say give your required height)?

Comment: well, tell one thing what you want...you want the paragraph height or the height of column which holds the paragraph ??

Comment: If you are thinking that you want the height of the paragraph then it depends on the text inside it and that will be really a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it in `v3` (I'm assuming that's what you're using). If you don't want the image displayed at all below `md` breakpoint (`991px`), just add `hidden-sm` and `hidden-xs` classes to the second `.col-md-6` and remove the `@media` block, as it's no longer needed.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.has-background img').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().css({
      backgroundImage:"url('"+$(this).attr('src')+"')"
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.equal-columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.equal-columns > * {
  flex:1
}
.has-background {
  background: transparent no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
}

.has-background img {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
 .has-background img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .equal-columns > * {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row equal-columns">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph.
        <p>Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph. 
        <p>Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph. 
        <p>Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph. 
        <p>Place holder paragaraph. Place holder paragaraph. 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 has-background">
       <img src="http://lorempixel.com/649/150/sports" />  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I used a tiny jQuery script to copy the `src` from the `<img>` as `background-image` in any `.has-background`. If you'd rather pass on the JavaScript, manually add `style="background-image:url('URL_OF_IMAGE')"` to the `<div>` element with class `has-background` - or set the `background-image` property value in CSS.
**Note:** You should crop the image close to the the size of the `<div>` containing paragraphs. If you don't, large areas of the image will get cropped (either from top/bottom or from left/right, depending on ratios of the image and the divs with paragraphs, possibly resulting in pixelation). Since you haven't specified anything, below `md` breakpoint I'm showing the image at 100% viewport width and proportional height (so it won't be equal to the paragraph. If you want them equal, it's possible using JavaScript.